# Acces storage from Azure Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

Trying to use the online powershell console in the Azure portal and need to access a file that is being stored in an Azure storage. Do I need to mount that storage in some way before I can access the file?

Comment: Do you mean that you have installed and configured Azure Powershell and want to use it to access the Portal?  If so, then you need to revise your question to make it clear what you have and have not tried.

Comment: Powershell was recently added to the portal bash so I am not using a local setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was found at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/powershell-comes-to-azure-cloud-shell/.
The dir command displays all available subscriptions and each has a default Clouddrive, so choose the relevant subscription by issuing dir "subscriptionname", followed by $home/clouddrive solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to issue Powershell commands to:

- Add the Azure account and subscription
- Set the Azure Storage account
- Obtain the blob(s) that you desire

Microsoft covers the commands to do that (and more) using Powershell commands. Without a more specific question, you will need to take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-powershell-guide-full to determine the specific commands that you will require.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Azure portal has a prompt for 'Azure CLI' and not Azure Powershell.

Comment: There is a preview in place